# install: "countinue" button could not be seen on "keyboard layout" selection

Tags: system-installation, keyboard-layout, vmware

I tried to install the Ubuntu 16.04 desktop version from vmware on Mac. After I selected the time zone, then it asked me to select keyboard layout. The screen is messed up, only partial of the "back" button can be seen, "continue" button could not be seen. If I click the partial back button, it goes back time zone selection, and only partial "back" button can be seen, and this button is grayed out, and I could not do anything.

I tried version 16.10 and 14.04, the same issue. I tried to turn off network, the same. [keyboard selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYeox.png)

Comment: I worked out by dragging the title bar, so "continue" button is showed up.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is related to the default screen resolution the VM is being displayed in.

When you get to the point again, take your mouse to top of dialog(menu bar), and click and hold, moving your mouse to the left, this should bring the button into view.

Alternately, Click on the Language Icon on the top bar, Mine is EN.
Select Text Entry Settings
Click on Tab: All Settings
Click on Displays
at this point, you should be able to select a resolution. I would recommend not going above 1024x768 until after the installation is complete. The apply button is at the lower right, and barely visible. click on this, and then click on the dialog which pops up, keep configuration.